# Phenology divergence color map per pixel

Tags: qgis, colormap

My aim is to create a map displaying the start of spring for vegetation which is a set average value, I want for each pixel to know on which date it is actually trespassing this value. So lets say pixel A is 4 days in advance to the average to trespass this value and is therefore colored in light blue, while pixel 2 is trespassing date of spring two days later than the set average and therefore colored in red.

How can I then create a "divergence colour shp file" which displays a color on each pixel regarding its range or distance to a set value?